# Missing Night Shift after upgrading to 9.3

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, night-shift

I don't see Night Shift after upgrading to IOS 9.3. I was using beta 9.3, but deleted the profile after I didn't see Night Shift in *Display & Brightness* after upgrading

Is there something I am missing?
 Using Ipod Touch 5th Gen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Night shift isn't supported on your hardware. See the footnote 1:

> Night Shift is available on iPhone 5s or later, iPad Pro, iPad Air or later, iPad mini 2 or later, and iPod touch (6th generation)

https://www.apple.com/ios/updates/

Comment: In my experience, Apple doesn't withhold a feature lightly. There is often a serious engineering hurdle preventing a feature when they release an OS and carve out older hardware to not support it. I can't speak to this specific limitation - but wanted to offer some thoughts @KalamalkaKid

Comment: Well, Apple sure did make an effort to make all apps that block blue light unavailable on their store (presumably so they could corner this market on iOS). This feature is why I wanted the Night Shift feature in the first place. Their obfuscation of useful apps like this makes me angry, and is just another reason to boycott their products.

Comment: PS - there is no engineering hurdle with Blue light reduction. Any Jailbroken iOS device can install the wonderful F.LUX app, which for whatever reason, is not available on iOS.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid the reason F.LUX isn't available on iOS is that the way it works requires access that isn't available to apps on regular iOS for security reasons. Source: https://justgetflux.com/ios.html

Comment: that doesnt explain why all the other blue light apps removed from the store

Comment: [According to f.lux - they used Private API on iOS](https://justgetflux.com/ios.html) which is explicit grounds for removal from the App Store. I don't know if that's the general reason - you'd need to ask Apple or the developer or possibly both and [look at the code](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231881/) to know if it uses the Metal API or OpenGLES 3.0 or not.

Answer (score 2):

I read on another forum that night shift requires a 64 bit system,, iPods are 32.  I can't confirm this , but it sounds possible. Could they have made 32 bit app, possibly,

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset the settings (don't reset the whole data, just general settings). I hope this will help you fix the issue. Can you enable the feature from the Settings app or is it even missing from there too?

Update: Night Shift isn't supportive for your version. More info from [here](http://appletoolbox.com/2016/03/top-three-ios-9-3-problems-how-to-fix/)

Comment: the feature is completely missing, so I am not sure if tis available on Ipods at all at this point. I have been on the phone for about 45 minutes with an Apple rep, and no one actually knows anything. I am currently reinstalling 9.3 from recovery mode to see if it will work.