# Why doesn't my iPhone 5c support Night Shift?

Tags: ios, iphone, night-shift

iOS 9.3 was released yesterday to the public and I have installed it on my iPhone 5c. What I'm wondering is, why is Night Shift not available for my phone? Is it the architecture of the processor, something to do with the screen, or perhaps something else?

Comment: [Planned obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence)

Comment: @Zack Are you sure that's really the reason? I don't see Apple executing such a petty act specifically on such a small functionality. If they really intended such thing they could just not release iOS 9 update for old devices altogether. The fact that it's not available on "32-bit" devices, not "old" devices, suggests it's much more likely software-related than deliberately planned. Still very unpleasant to the customers, of course.

Comment: @XiangJi Is there any source on the 64-bit only statement? I can't understand why it would only be possible on 64-bit devices.

Comment: @Zack See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231881/from-a-technical-standpoint-why-cant-night-shift-be-supported-on-32-bit-hardwa for some guesses as of the reason why.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Apple](http://www.apple.com/ios/updates/) site:

> Night Shift is available on iPhone 5s or later, iPad Pro, iPad Air or later, iPad mini 2 or later, and iPod touch (6th generation).

So I think It's related to 64bit processor architecture.

Answer (score 4):

You can install F.lux instead using xcode. It's not very complicated and it doesn't require you to jailbreak your phone at all and it's not a hack : https://justgetflux.com/sideload/ You'll just have to download the project file from another website as they've deleted it following apple's demand to take it down. It works nicely on my 5C.

Comment: I thought that Apple got rid of sideloading, though.

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: You can no longer sideload flux on iOS, it has been removed

Comment: this is such BS. This is a health issue and apple is making it very difficult fro people with 32 bit devices to protect their eyes.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid It's not your eyes that need protecting, but your sleep patterns. A blue screen late at night will not damage your eyes.

Comment: @MikeScott  you are correct! WE all need good sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I might guess, based on insight from being a software developer: The f.lux page says that it is no longer available because it doesn't use the documented API and Apple doesn't like them getting around it. The new Night Shift feature is part of a new iOS release, so it must use a *newly added* API feature.  That feature may be added for current devices only and it would be different to implement on older devices, and they did not put that work into it because it's obsolecent.

Comment: iPhone 5c also runs iOS 9.3 that it should have the same infrastructure as others. Although I'm not certain of the exact reason, it must be something technical that if applied, would lead to worse performance.

Comment: It's a different SoC. Drivers accessing video driver features would be different, and need to be written specifically for it. @CanSürmeli  The A6 is discontinued,  so they didn't address the particular features with the software. E.g. how to communicate with the DAC LUT (if it's even exposed in the same way).

Comment: I haven't thought of more low level stuff at first but I just compiled and ran f.lux on my iPhone 5 and it worked just allright. The screen is yellowish. So if f.lux team can achieve this with private APIs even on an iPhone 5 then naturally Apple can as well. Therefore it's related with something else and not drivers or etc.